# Call php code after html button click

Tags: php, html

I would like to call PHP code when I click on Download Now. Following is my HTML and PHP code:

```
<?php
$test = "Function Call Successful";
?>

<html>
Hello there!
<a href='upload.php?hello=true'>Download now</a>
</html>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['hello'])) {
    echo $test;
  }
?>
```

The problem in when I click on Download now, it reloads the page and doesn't display anything. I would like the page to remember value of `$test` and print its value as soon as I click on Download Now.

Comment: change $_POST['hello'] to $_GET['hello']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters can be accessed using `GET` or `REQUEST`, and `POST` is used to access variables passed to the current script via the `HTTP POST` method ( when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request).

Try with

```
if(isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    echo $test;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Jenz. I tried it, but it didn't work. I think its because when I click on Download now, it just reloads the page,. I would like the page to continue and just print the value of $test, than taking the value again..

Comment: @RaviSingh..I tried this in my local and is working well. Check whether there is any other error in your page.

Comment: found the error message.. It says:  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: hello  on line 186" while reading response header from upstream

Comment: what is your line 186?

Comment: That was echo($_GET['hello']);.. But we can ignore it as I was just testing, why it isn't working.. Not sure what else could be wrong,,

Comment: From the code you have shared, I can't find any issues. Anyway wherever you are calling URL parameter, you have to check whether it is set or not using `isset()` otherwise it will return error as mentioned above.

Comment: Or is there any way to point to same file, than href='upload.php?hello=true'?? Can I just just something like href='.?hello=true'

Answer (score 0):

You need to set $_GET variable on if condition.

Please try below code.

```
<?php
$test = "Function Call Successful";
?>

<html>
Hello there!
<a href='upload.php?hello=true'>Download now</a>
</html>

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    echo $test;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys..

_GET instead of _POST did actually help in resolving the issue.

@jenz, Thanks for helping me in finding other bugs in my code too mate.. :)